# Index 1 out of bounds for length 1 Error Java how to fix?

Tags: java, arrays

I have been trying to fix this index out of bounds error for some time but cannot seem to do so. This program is supposed to be my solution to ACSL Contest 3: Create A Tree. The question is below

Given a string to create 2 parallel arrays, process the letters in the string from left to right, inserting each letter into the first array in alphabetical order, one letter at a time. During this process, each letter is assigned an integer value in the second array as follows:

The first letter has a value of 0. If the new letter is the first or last in the array, its value is one more than the value of the adjacent letter. Otherwise, it is one more than the larger value of the two adjacent values. If the letter is already in the array, the new letter is placed before the existing letter. Once the two arrays are created, output the letters in order of their value, from left to right, starting with the 0, then all of the 1s, then all of the 2s, etc. For example, if someone input "PYTHONN" into the function, it would output "PHYOTNN."

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
public class CreateTree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "PYTHONN"; 
        List<Character> L = new ArrayList<>(); 
        List<Integer> V = new ArrayList<>(); 
        V.add(-1);

        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) { 
            L.add(c); 
            Collections.sort(L); 
            int i = L.indexOf(c); 
            V.add(i+1, Math.max(V.get(i), V.get(i+1)) + 1); //rule 2
            }

        Collections.sort(L, (a, b) -> V.remove(1)); 
        System.out.println(L.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining()));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Variable names should begin in lowercase, so they don't get confused with class names, which start in uppercase.